# Video are not able to rendered in WebView android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, video, android-webview

I am using a **WebView** to render a page from my website. The page contains audio and visual contents. I tried to render this link on my app but **WebView** shows blank data. If I use any URL of "YouTube" video or "Vimeo" then I video played successfully in app. I don't know why my  website page is not rendered properly in **WebView**.

Video page rended but video not played and I am not able to below content of page also.

WebView Picture when Loads Page:

[image: WebView Picture when Loads Page]

Original Page of Website

[image: Original Page of Website]

Code:

```
           myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://demourl.com/demo/index.html?cpath=embedded-player&ocode=frff&pcode=fff&signup=https%3A%2F%2Forder.dddd.com%2Fcheckout%2Frp%2Fmonthly%2F30d%3Fcpath%3Dembedded-player#/playlists/mp.45666");
}



public class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
        // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
        if (mCustomView != null) {
            callback.onCustomViewHidden();
            return;
        }
        mContentView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        mContentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mCustomViewContainer = new FrameLayout(Demo.this);
        mCustomViewContainer.setLayoutParams(LayoutParameters);
        mCustomViewContainer.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.black);
        view.setLayoutParams(LayoutParameters);
        mCustomViewContainer.addView(view);
        mCustomView = view;
        mCustomViewCallback = callback;
        mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setContentView(mCustomViewContainer);
    }
```

Please Help